# After insert table element with children into Word using C# and OpenXml, document does not open

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml

If I inserting an empty table, everything works fine, but when I try to imitate real table with it's children, like this created directly in word...
here is its structure:

[image]

I have such an error when opening the file:

[image]

I'm using **.Net5.0** and **.docx** word extension,
nuget is: **DocumentFormat.OpenXml v2.16.0**

Code:

```
Body rawBody = wdDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
var tbl = ArrangeWordElement.Arrange_Table(3, 2);
rawBody.Append(tbl);

public static Table Arrange_Table(int cols, int rows)
    {
        var tbl = new Table();

        tbl.Append(Arrange_TableProperties());
        tbl.Append(Arrange_TableGrid(cols));

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            tbl.Append(Arrange_TableRow(cols));

        return tbl;
    }

    public static TableProperties Arrange_TableProperties()
    {
        var tblProp = new TableProperties();
        
        tblProp.Append(Arrange_TableStyle());
        tblProp.Append(Arrange_TableWidth());
        tblProp.Append(Arrange_TableLook());

        return tblProp;
    }

    public static TableStyle Arrange_TableStyle()
    {
        return new TableStyle();
    }

    public static TableWidth Arrange_TableWidth()
    {
        return new TableWidth();
    }

    public static TableLook Arrange_TableLook()
    {
        return new TableLook();
    }
    
    public static Paragraph Arrange_Paragraph()
    {
        var paragraph = new Paragraph();
        
        paragraph.Append(Arrange_ParagraphProperties());
        paragraph.Append(Arrange_Run());

        return paragraph;
    }

    public static TableGrid Arrange_TableGrid(int cols)
    {
        var tblGrid = new TableGrid();

        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
        {
            tblGrid.Append(Arrange_GridColumn());
        }
        
        return tblGrid;
    }

    public static GridColumn Arrange_GridColumn()
    {
        return new GridColumn();
    }

    public static TableRow Arrange_TableRow(int cols)
    {
        var tblRow = new TableRow();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
        {
            tblRow.Append(Arrange_TableCell());
        }

        return tblRow;
    }
    
    public static TableCell Arrange_TableCell()
    {
        var tblCell = new TableCell();
        tblCell.Append(Arrange_TableCellProperties());
        tblCell.Append(Arrange_Paragraph());
        
        return tblCell;
    }
    
    public static TableCellProperties Arrange_TableCellProperties()
    {
        var tblCellProp = new TableCellProperties();
        tblCellProp.Append(Arrange_TableCellWidth());

        return tblCellProp;
    }

    public static TableCellWidth Arrange_TableCellWidth()
    {
        return new TableCellWidth();
    }
    
    public static RunProperties Arrange_RunProperties()
    {
        var runProps = new RunProperties();
        runProps.Append(new Bold());
        runProps.Append(new BoldComplexScript());
        runProps.Append(new Italic());
        runProps.Append(new ItalicComplexScript());
        runProps.Append(new Color());
        runProps.Append(new FontSize());
        runProps.Append(new FontSizeComplexScript());
        runProps.Append(new Highlight());
        runProps.Append(new Underline());

        return runProps;
    }

    public static ParagraphProperties Arrange_ParagraphProperties()
    {
        var paragraphProp = new ParagraphProperties();
        paragraphProp.Append(Arrange_ParagraphMarkRunProperties());
        
        return paragraphProp;
    }

    public static ParagraphMarkRunProperties Arrange_ParagraphMarkRunProperties()
    {
        var pmrp = new ParagraphMarkRunProperties();
        pmrp.Append(new Bold());
        pmrp.Append(new BoldComplexScript());
        pmrp.Append(new Italic());
        pmrp.Append(new ItalicComplexScript());
        pmrp.Append(new Color());
        pmrp.Append(new FontSize());
        pmrp.Append(new FontSizeComplexScript());
        pmrp.Append(new Highlight());
        pmrp.Append(new Underline());

        return pmrp;
    }

    public static Text Arrange_Text()
    {
        return new Text();
    }

    public static Run Arrange_Run()
    {
        var run = new Run();
        
        run.Append(Arrange_RunProperties());
        run.Append(Arrange_Text());
        
        return run;
    }
```

Comment: Please share your code and if you ran it thru the validator

Comment: @DanielA.White i've added my code

Comment: @DanielA.White thank you, I didn't know there was such thing like validator. I go through  all errors and everything works fine ;)